# How do i load/run an external .js script from Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am running a Protractor test that will verify various elements on a website, but before doing this I want to run an external JavaScript script with arguments using node which will set up some prerequisites beforehand.
However, I am completely stuck as to how I would run the "javascript_code.js" script from the protractor.

I know the protractor code below is completely wrong, I have just used the describe/it layout to show where I want to do what and where:

```
describe('Validate elements on website',function(){

    // reference and run the javascript_code.js
    require('C:\<file path>\Javascript_code.js');
    Run "node javascript_code.js arg1 arg2 arg3"

    it('Validate onscreen elements', function(){
        
        <Do website verification>
     });
    });
```

Comment: Added "RunJavascript": "node Javascript_code.js 1 2 3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach will depend on what you're doing in your js file. If your code is synchronous, the easiest way is to make your javascript_code.js a function, that takes parameters and then export it, like so

```
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
};
```

and then `require` and invoke your function

```
let your_func = require('C:\<file path>\Javascript_code.js');
your_func(arg1, arg2);

describe('Validate elements on website',function(){

    it('Validate onscreen elements', function(){

    });
});
```

However, if your js code is asynchronous the approach should be different. Let me know

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, it solves half my problem:) 

If i put the code you recommended (below) into a script called "main_script.js" and run it from command line using "node main_script.js" it works perfectly:

let your_func = require('C:\<file path>\Javascript_code.js');
your_func(arg1, arg2);


However, if i include that code into my Protractor script, the Protractor script successfully runs but it does not run the above code, and if i try running the Protractor script as a node application it errors on the Describe is not defined.

Comment: run your code in onPrepare block of configuration

Comment: I have added the code to the onPrepare block within my config file, but it still isn't running all the items in the function. I have added a console.log("This is the function") within the function being called to make sure the block is being run, which it is, so i am not sure why the python script i am also running in that function is not being run.

Comment: The problem was that the function wasn't being given time to finish. I had to use a async/await function in order to allow this. This also (for anyone else who might need to use this function) does not work in Eclipse so use Visual Studio Code

Comment: This is what I said in the last line of my answer @JessaBrandy sounds like you solved the problem?